# host adapter vs bios

Tags: hardware-raid, storage-spaces

recently I had to create a raid 10 from 32 disks using the LSI 3108 hardware raid card. But after I create the virtual drives and initialize them, I got this msg in the boot prompt,

"2 virtual drive handled by host adapter"
"0 virtual drive handled by BIOS".

First I ignored the message and installed CentOs in the drive and it was installed perfectly. But when I reboot the server, BIOS does not detect any boot media. I don't know what might be issue.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you attached 4Kn drives?

From https://www.broadcom.com/support/knowledgebase/1211161504004/booting-from-a-virtual-drive-vd-that-uses-4k-drives-with-megarai

> If the motherboard BIOS is set to 'legacy' mode, then at boot you may see that the 4K VD will be reported by the LSI MegaRAID BIOS, but you will see the **'0 are handled by BIOS'** message.  This indicates that the VD is not being exported to the operating system by the controller, and thus you will not be able to boot from that VD.  This is happening because the 'legacy' BIOS setting of the motherboard doesn't understand the 4K sector size.  'Legacy' BIOS supports booting from disk drives with the industry standard 512 byte sector size.

The only solution is to switch to 512e drives, or to switch from BIOS to UEFI booting.